# Cannot determine correct logic for exit condition

Tags: python

I am measuring voltages. The voltages are collected into a logfile. The voltage starts around 5 volts, climbs over 200 volts, then drops back down below 150 volts. My program is supposed to not put voltage readings into the logfile until voltage is above 150. Then after voltage has gone over 150, peaked around 250 and is dropping back down, the program is supposed to do a sys.exit when voltage has dropped below 150. The problem is that my program is doing the sys.exit too early, as the voltage first climbs, when the voltage is below 150. My program is shown below. I was hoping to avoid this problem by indenting next to last line, thinking that this would not allow this line to be active until after the voltage had already climbed over 150 volts and was dropping back down under 150 volts. Any suggestions?

```
with open('logfile.txt', 'w') as f:

    while True:
        volts = adc.readADCDifferential01(1056, 8)
        if volts > 150:
            print >> f, time(), volts
            if volts < 150:
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: You don't ever show where `volts` is defined.  How does it change in the loop?  where does it come from?

Comment: When does the value of `volts` ever change? As indented, your program would never exit, since `volts` cannot simultaneously be greater than and less than 150.

Comment: Please try to pick a title (question) that actually gives some information. *Every single* python 2.7 question is described by the same title as yours. (Done: thank you, @chepner! FYI, the original title was something like "Python 2.7 program doesn't work")

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title to something a little closer to the actual question.

Comment: Yes, my title was too vague.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

with open('logfile.txt', 'w') as f:

```
while volts>150:
      print >> f, time(), volts
      volts=voltfunction()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: It will not, because volts doesn't change inside the loop.

Comment: Changed the logic to volts changing inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Rather lame, but does the job:

```
>>> voltages = [50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 200, 150, 100, 50]
>>> threshold_passed = False
>>> for v in voltages:
...     if v > 150:
...         print v
...         threshold_passed = True
...     if threshold_passed and v < 150:
...         print v
...         break
... 
170
200
250
200
170
100
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a state variable to keep track over whether or not you've hit 150 volts yet.  Something like this:

```
with open('logfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    reachedPeak = False
    while True:
        volts = adc.readADCDifferential01(1056, 8)
        if volts > 150:
            reachedPeak = True
            print >> f, time(), volts
        if volts < 150 and reachedPeak:
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Sorry, also didn't work. Still did sys.exit as voltage was first climbing.

Comment: That's not possible unless your volts don't go up constantly.  Like it hits 151, but then drops to 149 before resuming the increasing.

Comment: I think it will work if the first 150 is raised up to 180. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
with open('logfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    threshold_crossed = False
    while True:
        volts = adc.readADCDifferential01(1056, 8)
        if volts > 150:
            threshold_crossed = True
        if threshold_crossed:
            print >> f, time(), volts
            if volts < 150:
                sys.exit()
```

I'm not sure how the code that you posted actually worked.  The `sys.exit` statement is guarded by mutually exclusive conditions:

```
if volts > 150:
    ...
    if volts < 150
        sys.exit()
```

Since `volts` does not change between the two `if` statements, if it passes the first, then it has a value greater than 150.  The second `if` statement is **always** `False` since the value can never be less than 150.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. Still did sys.exit as voltage was first climbing.

Answer (score 0):

However, this does work:

```
with open('logfile.txt, 'w') as f:
    threshold_crossed = False
    while True:
        volts = adc.readADCDifferential01(1056, 8)
        if volts > 150:
            print >> f, time(), volts
            if volts > 180:
                threshold_crossed = True
            if threshold_crossed and volts < 160:
                sys.exit()
```

Thanks for your help, you certainly led me in the right direction!